# show article list with thumbnail,author and hits

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Firstly I am a new comer for Joomla.

I have created section named "Test" then category named "hello" & lastly a new article named "sample" in side this article I have inserted one image & some data.
Then I have created a new menu under Article->Category list layout.
When I click on this menu it was display like

sr.no         Title            Author         Hits
1             sample        administrator    -

but i want to show small image instead of sr.no 1,2,3,...etc. How I can show image.Please give me some ideas about component/module/plugin joomla or changes in existing code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this extensions for what you want to do:

[News Show Pro GK4](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/frontend-news/7738)

Thanks,
Afshin